# android emulator cannot connect localhost dev server

Tags: javascript, android, vue.js, ionic-framework

I've an Ionic app that interacts with a server both via REST and sockets.

While I've no issues at all running it via `ionic serve` and iOS simulator, it seems that on Android emulator I cannot reach a locally running development server.

I've read several posts suggested not to use `127.0.0.1` because it actually serves as loopback for the emulator itself, so I've switched using `10.0.2.2`.
Still no luck.

Then I've read that I should do some more extra configurations in the manifest file.

Below is some of the relevant code sections:

```html
<script>
import {isPlatform} from "@ionic/vue";

export const devServerURL = isPlatform('android') ? 'http://10.0.2.2:8008' : 'http://127.0.0.1:8008';
export const prodServerURL = `https://blabla.xyz`;
export const serverURL = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? devServerURL : prodServerURL;

alert(process.env.NODE_ENV + ' ' + serverURL);  // DEBUG PRINT

export default {
  // eslint-disable-next-line vue/multi-word-component-names
  name: 'Config',
}
</script>
```

The above alert is shown as: `development http://10.0.2.2:8008` so I know for a fact the app gets the correct settings to start with.

In addition here are the relevant parts of the manifest file:

```xml
<application android:allowBackup="true"
                 android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                 android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                 android:supportsRtl="true"
                 android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
                 android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
                 android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
...
```

network_security_config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.2.2</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.4.104</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Still no luck.

Funny enough, the only workaround I've found working for me was keep using `http://127.0.0.1:8008` and right after the emulator is running, run the below command:

`adb reverse tcp:8008 tcp:8008`

Can anyone point me to the correct approach?

**UPDATE:**

here's the error I'm getting in logcat:

```
2022-04-20 17:30:54.842 22224-22224/blabla.xyz E/Capacitor/Console: File: webpack://storyApp/./node_modules/engine.io-client/build/esm/transports/websocket.js? - Line 64 - Msg: WebSocket connection to 'ws://10.0.2.2:8008/ws/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED
```

Comment: I think `http://127.0.0.1:8008` will not work you have to change to your Computer IP something like: `https://192.168.123.123:8008`. google how to find PC IP.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib At the very last part of my question, I've shown a workaround to make it work, but I want to take the correct approach. I've also tried using the computer IP and ended up with the same results

Comment: 10.0.2.2 should work. And you do not need a network_security_config file. Only the uses clear text traffic flag.

Comment: Try that 10.0.2.2 url with a browser on the emulator.

Comment: @blackapps I took your advice but if didn't help (got rid of the extra xml file and only used the clear text element), but when I'm opening chrome in the emulator I still get "No Internet" and "ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED" errors

Comment: And a browser on the PC works?

Comment: @blackapps yes. as well as iOS simulator

Comment: I have the same issues, did you find another way to make it work? I don't even have the "proxy" options in the Emulator/Settings for some reason, it's very very strange, I suspect Android Studio was recently updated and there is a mishap somewhere.

Comment: @gaborous Sadly no

Comment: @Ben I've found a solution but I am using an Angular server, the solution was to supply the argument `--host 0.0.0.0` to force the server to attach to all adapters, not just the first one it found. For some reason, these dev servers tend to get confused with virtual machine adapters and such. There often is a similar command for most server softwares, I guess for Ionic too. An alternative is to try another server like Xampp, if you can access it from inside the Android emulator, then it's indeed a problem of the Ionic server being confused with the network adapters.